# BCM4312 speed is very slow

Tags: wireless, lenovo

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1713] (rev 02)
```

Above are the Wired & Wireless Cards of my laptop Lenovo G550. I was a fedora user and than since I had some issues with Fedora 17 I moved to Ubuntu, I liked it but there are so many issues going on with Broadcom cards, following are the issues I have faced and noticed always.

1. My wireless card does not support HW550-3G - Aztech routers, the LAN works fine but the internet stops in less than a minute and its too annoying it never works again.
2. If I download something from my Dual Boot Windows, because I have 40Mbps connection, it takes 2 minutes to download 50MB of file where UBUNTU takes 8 minutes and the download speed is around 200KB/sec where windows boost upto 3MB/sec
3. Again wherever I go, page loading is dead slow.
4. I tried even connecting USB wireless still there is no change in download speed. Thinking that it might be the issue of my wireless card.
5. Please advise me if there are issues with broadcom or is there any driver update because whenever I try updating my driver it says, I can't because I have low powered bcm43xx card. Should I change it or simply switch to WINDOWS or FEDORA again?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was only about the slow account of VPN I had set up, which was running on every reboot. I removed the OpenVPN network plugin the speed came back up to normal.